# регулярные выражения для знака "-"

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь сделать регулярку, чтобы определить, начинается ли строка со знака `-`

Пока сделал:

```
var ifminus = str.search( /\-/d);
```

Перепробовал уже около 20 вариантов, в интернете есть подсказки на все, а тут фиг найдешь. Мне нужно определить, начинается ли строка с этого знака, и потом его удалить.

Comment: `str.indexOf('-') == 0` значит начинается с минуса

Comment: что это за флаг вообще такой "d"? O_o `str.replace(/^-/, '')`

Comment: да я уже сам запутался, что в интернете находил. то и писал))

Answer (score 1):

```
var str    = '-3213213';
var search = str.search(/^-/);

console.log( search );// Вернет:0 - совпадение найдено, это будет позиция символа. Если -1 значит не найдено
```

Comment: Почему не `test`? В чем смысл оперировать числами, а не булевыми для подобной задачи?

Comment: @MedvedevDev как в вопросе было, так и подсказал, чтобы понятно было на примере вопроса.

Comment: Так у вас ничего кроме 0 и -1 регулярка и не даст, это равносильно true/false. Ну да ладно.

Comment: @MedvedevDev search нужно проверять не на true/false, так как если он возвращает 0 - это уже результат.

Comment: у вас задача: понять есть ли в начале строки "-" или нет .... у вас только 2 варианта да/нет, вам не нужны другие варианты, тогда зачем городить потом `if(search === 0)` если можно просто `if(search)`... я к этому

Comment: @MedvedevDev Ну я ответил с такой функцией, с какой спросил автор, чтобы ему было понятнее. Не пойму о чем спор

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял требование именно к строке? И возвращать надо тоже строку?
В таком случае решение может быть следующим:

```js
var str = '-856';
var ifminus = str.search(/^-\d+/);
if (ifminus == 0) {
    str = 0 - str
};
console.log("'" + str + "'");
```

Впрочем, при наличии динамической типизации в js можно воспользоваться тернарным оператором.
Тогда можно таким образом:

```js
var anotherstr = '-1255';
anotherstr > 0 ? anotherstr : anotherstr = 0 - anotherstr;
console.log("'" + anotherstr + "'");
```